# Compilar C no Sublime Text

Tags: c, sublime-text-2

Estou usando `Windows`, e preciso saber como compilar programas escritos em `C` neste editor. No `ubuntu` é mais fácil, mas no `Windows 8.1` eu não sei como fazer. Estou usando `Sublime Text 2`, pois é o meu editor preferido.

Comment: Normalmente no windows é necessario baixar um compilador de C, algumas IDEs como o [devc++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/), [codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) ja instalam um, o [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) é outra opção

Comment: Procure pelo `CodeBlocks`.
Quando precisei fazer um trabalho sobre C no meu Windows 8 ele me atendeu muito bem. Tanto no editor quanto no compilador.

Comment: A Microsoft fornece uma versao gratuita do Visual Studio (podes continuar a usar o teu editor integrado no IDE da microsoft, mas isso da algum trabalho) https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx

Comment: Os editores nao compilam programas.

Comment: @pmg quem compila é o compilador, mas o editor manda ele compilar, o que dá quase no mesmo ;-)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. estou tentando !

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema? Caso ainda não diga o que aconteceu que podemos ajudar.

Comment: ainda não. desisti e agora to usando code blocks  :(

Comment: Não gosto muito do codeblocks, prefiro o Sublime. Chegou a tentar fazer o que eu sugeri? Eu fiz aqui e deu certo. Qualquer coisa diga onde deu erro pra você.

Comment: Cara, é muito simples compilar C no sublime text 2. veja esse vídeo que eu mesmo fiz. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bACxGtkzpX0

Comment: ou se quiser, procure pelo nome no youtube: "como configurar o Sublime Text com compilador C/C++"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Baixe o MinGW (*GCC portado para Windows*) [nesse site](http://www.mingw.org/), instale-o e o adicione as variáveis do sistema.

Clique em *Tools > Build System > New Build System*, na janela que abrir coloque o código abaixo:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell" : true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

Salve com o nome `C.sublime-build`.

Mude o BuildSytem para o C: Tools > BuildSystem > C.

Escreva um código em C e compile pressionando <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> ou no menu *Tools > Build*.

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: [How do I compile and run a C program in Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18100051/1964435)

Comment: Configure até o Javac (e java) e csc (c#) assim pra testes rápidos, obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

O sublime textbox é apenas um editor de textos com funcionalidades avançadas o que ele faz é apenas dar um highlight em palavras chaves, completa certos termos etc.

Uma IDE principalmente para linguaguens de tipagem estatica é compostas por dois elementos as funcionalidades avançadas de manipulação de texto e o compilador, que é o responsável por analizar o código fonte, verificar se existem erros e por último ele gera os artefatos.

Como na Linux normalmente já vem algum compilador de C isso não é  problema, no windows é necessário instalar(gcc ou mingw) um, algumas  IDEs que já fazem isso são:

[CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

[DevC++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/)

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver com o [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) instalado é só aperta `Ctrl + B`.